# Can one BibTex file contains same key multiple times?

Tags: bibtex

Can one BibTex file contains same key multiple times?

```
@article{Carberry_2012, title={The Memory Bus Considered Harmful}, volume={9}, url={http://dx.doi.org/10.5555/666655554444}, DOI={10.5555/666655554444}, number={11}, journal={Journal of Psychoceramics}, publisher={CrossRef test user}, author={Carberry, Josiah}, year={2012}, month={Oct}, pages={1-3} ,doi = {10.5555/666655554444} }
@article{Carberry_2012, title={Deconstructing Write-Back Caches}, volume={9}, url={http://dx.doi.org/10.5555/777766665555}, DOI={10.5555/777766665555}, number={11}, journal={Journal of Psychoceramics}, author={Carberry, Josiah}, year={2012}, month={Oct}, pages={1-3} ,doi = {10.5555/777766665555} }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The key is used to identify an entry. Therefore the keys must be unique.

Answer (score 7):

Running bibtex:

```
voss@shania:~/Mist> bibtex test
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: test.bib
Repeated entry---line 2 of file test.bib
 : @article{Carberry_2012
 :                       , title={Deconstructing Write-Back Caches}, volume={9}, url={http://dx.doi.org/10.5555/777766665555}, DOI={10.5555/777766665555}, number={11}, journal={Journal of Psychoceramics}, author={Carberry, Josiah}, year={2012}, month={Oct}, pages={1-3} ,doi = {10.5555/777766665555} }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
(There was 1 error message)
```

The second entry is ignored and the first one is used.